# Sending emails in asp.net with specific name instead of sender email

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

I need to send an email in asp.net but I need sender appears like "MySiteName" without `info@example.com`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Like this:

```
using(MailMessage message = new MailMessage(
        new MailAddress("You@Domain.example", "Your Name"),
        new MailAddress("Recipient@OtherDomain.example", "Their Name")
    )) {
    message.Subject = ...;
    message.Body = ...;

    new SmtpClient().Send(message);
}
```

You will need to enter the `SmtpClient`'s connection settings in `Web.config`

Answer (score 10):

you could try something like this

```
MailAddress from = new MailAddress("info@example.com", "MySiteName");
```

More info here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress.aspx

Answer (score 6):

There are 2 ways, if you are using [MailAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh392kbs) you can use the [constructor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s17zfkf(v=VS.100).aspx) to input the display name, or simply format the recipient address as `MySiteName <info@mysitename>`

For a downloadable example see [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sendemail)

Answer (score 2):

This is how it works.

```
MailMessage message;
//prepare message
message.Sender = new MailAddress("Sender-email-id", "Sender Name");
new SmtpClient().Send(message);
```