# C# Customising MailAddress.From field not working

Tags: c#, email, smtp, gmail

I am trying to send Emails from my custom address to users using C# and googles smtp service. My problem is that when the when the user receives the message it is displayed `admin@customDomain.co.uk <myAddress@gmail.com>` in the from section of the email.

My problem is that I want the user to see `admin@customDomain.co.uk <admin@customDomain.co.uk>`. Is this possible using the google service? Or should I look at some other option? If so what?

I have tried the answers on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2737699/sending-emails-in-asp-net-with-specific-name-instead-of-sender-email) thread but non worked and I also found this [google blog post](https://gmail.googleblog.com/2009/07/send-mail-from-another-address-without.html) but I cant work out how it can solve my issue

**My Code**

```
    string SmtpAddress = "smtp.gmail.com";
    int MyPort = 587;
    bool enableSSL = true;
    string MyPassword = "somePassword";
    string MyUsername = "aUsername";

    public string EmailFrom = "admin@customDomain.co.uk";
    public string Subject = "Test Subject";

public void Send(string body, BL.Customer customer)
    {
        using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage())
        {
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(customer.EmailAddress));
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(customer.SCEmailAddress))
            {
                //message.To.Add(new MailAddress(customer.SCEmailAddress));
            }
            message.From = new MailAddress(EmailFrom, EmailFrom);
            message.Subject = Subject;
            message.Body = string.Format(body);
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;

            using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
            {
                var credential = new NetworkCredential
                {
                    UserName = MyUsername,
                    Password = MyPassword
                };
                smtp.Credentials = credential;
                smtp.Host = SmtpAddress;
                smtp.Port = MyPort;
                smtp.EnableSsl = enableSSL;
                try
                {
                    smtp.Send(message);
                }
                catch (SmtpException se)
                {
                    throw se;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: try using the EmailAddress class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending email in .NET through Gmail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)

Comment: The problem is that Google (or more accurately, your account) doesn't have "permission" to send from that address so it uses your logged in address instead. If you want to send email from a particular address, you will almost certainly have to use a commercial ail provider and prove that you own the domain too.